# Chrome Extension Manifest 2 problems

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following Chrome Extension manifest which is not formatting the indents properly which tells me I have not created the manifest properly - however, I just can't see the problem.

```
{
  "name": "ReportIt",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "Immediately Remove and report Child Pornography",  
  "icons": { "16": "images/icon-128.png", "128": "images/icon-128.png" },


  "content_scripts": [{ 
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["scripts/contentscript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": false
    }],

    "background": {
      "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"]
      },

      "permissions": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*",
      "contextMenus"
      ],
      "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
      "web_accessible_resources": [
      "bower_components/angular/*",
      "scripts/background.js"
      ]
    }
```

**What is wrong with the formatting of the above Chrome Extension Manifest?**

Comment: Sorry, I'll have to downvote this. Your manifest works fine, and you can validate that using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). The fact that auto-indent in some editor is failing to work properly is not a problem with the code.

Comment: There is no "standard" indentation in [JSON](http://json.org/). In fact, all whitespace is completely optional. As long as this passes validation, there's _nothing_ wrong.

Comment: No need to down vote - it was a valid question and you provided information in your comment that helped me and others! @Xan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version working for me without any problem:

```
{
  "name": "ReportIt",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  // "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "Immediately Remove and report Child Pornography",
  "icons": {
    // "16": "images/icon-128.png",
    // "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },


  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["scripts/contentscript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": false
  }],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "bower_components/angular/*",
    "scripts/background.js"
  ]
}
```

Might be you could send exact error message and Chrome version ?

Comment: No error - just indentation in Sublime is not correct which suggests the content of the JSON is not correct

Comment: Seems it's a issue in sublime. Just ignore it.